# Filtering out the #more anchor link that gets produced by <!--more-->

Tags: functions, filters

Back in my naive days of theming, I had to make it so the link inserted by `<!--more-->` wouldn't dump the viewer at the anchor it produces.

I made a dinky plugin that consisted of:

```
function No_More_Link($buffer) {
  $inHTML[0] = '/#more-\d+/';
  $outHTML[0] = '';
  return preg_replace($inHTML, $outHTML, $buffer);
}
ob_start("No_More_Link");
```

Years later, I thought I could do much better, by using a filter in the theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function no_more_link ( $input ) {
  return preg_replace( '/#more-\d+/', '', $input );
}
add_filter( 'get_permalink', 'no_more_link' );
```

This doesn't work. I've tried bumping up the priority to ridiculous levels.

Am I applying the filter to the wrong thing? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter [`the_content_more_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post-template.php#L219) hook and remove `#more-POST_ID` from the link:

```
function wpse_51806_strip_more_link( $more_link ) {
    global $id;
    return str_replace( "#more-$id", '', $more_link );
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'wpse_51806_strip_more_link' );
```

It has even been made into [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/striptease), if you're more comfortable with plugins then code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

you are kind-of asking to re-invent the wheel - http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Link_Jumps_to_More_or_Top_of_Page

some background:
the 'more-link' gets added in /wp-includes/post-template.php line 217 (in wp3.2) as part of the `get_the_content()` function;

```
  $output .= apply_filters( 'the_content_more_link', ' <a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link\">$more_link_text</a>", $more_link_text );
```